# TCP client register/login using hashmap java

Tags: java, tcp, tcpclient, tcpserver

I've been struggling with this for the past 2 days.

Im supposed to have a client/server java in eclipse for my computer network class, but the point is we never coded in java, it was kinda forced on us to rushlearn java for the past week.

on the console im suposed to write: 
register   OR login

How can i check the first word on a string, if it equals register store the username and password in a hashmap and if it equals login check the hashmap for comparison?

this is my code so far:

SERVER:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class TCPServer {

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
    {

        String clientSentence;
        String capitalizedSentence;

        HashMap<List<String>, List<String>> userMap = new HashMap<List<String>, List<String>>();


        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(5201);

        while (true) {

            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();

            capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase() + '\n';

            outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);


            }


    }
}
```

CLIENT

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class TCPClient {


    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
    {

        String sentence;
        String modifiedSentence;
        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 5201);

        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
        outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');

        modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
        System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);
        inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        clientSocket.close();

    }
}
```

How should i proceed from now?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You first need to understand, what does this statement do. Actually what does the parameter of this function do:

> public static void main(String argv[])

In the console if you type login, argv[0] will have login.
If you type register, argv[0] will have register.

in console when you run the program if you type register login, then argv[0] will have register, arvg[1] will have login.

Hint:

```
if(argv[0].equals("register")){
} else if(argv[0].equals("login")){
}else{
System.out.println("Please enter correct option");
System.exit(0);
}
```

So based on the argument you can direct the code to where you want.

Comment: Thank you i wil ltry doing as you said, will post teh results.